# Uso de 200vw afetando a altura do HTML no Chrome Mobile

Tags: html, css, react

Olá!

Estou construindo um pequeno portfolio em React com scroll lateral. Para isso, criei um container de altura 100vh e comprimento 200vw, para armazenar duas telas que farão o scroll.

Tudo funciona bem no Firefox, mas quando abro o projeto no Chrome Mobile parece que a width de 200vw é aplicada também ao hight, que dobra o tamanho do viewport. Tentei trocar para %, mas o efeito se repetiu.

Caso alguém já tenha passado por isso, agradeço o apoio. O código completo está em https://codepen.io/michelmarechal/pen/rXvMLz

```
#wrapper {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 200vw;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
```

Comment: Cara coloca o código completo ai, HTML/CSS e JS se estiver usando. só como o CSS dessa tag ai não da para te responder nada que não seja chutando

Comment: Olá! Muito obrigado, Hugo! Estou usando React nesse projeto, que ainda está no começo. Se puder dar uma olhada no projeto no CodePen, ajudaria muito: https://codepen.io/michelmarechal/pen/rXvMLz